# Making the output of CNN filters the new CNN filters for a larger 3d trainable random array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Sorry for the poor wording of the question but basically I am trying to do this:

1) Say I convolve an input with CNN filters, and get back feature maps of (batch x, y, 5, 10) where x and y are dimensions that depend on input size, strides etc and 10 is the number of features maps

2) So now instead of having these feature maps be the input to the next layer, and doing a convolution on them,
I want these feature maps to represent my new CNN filters themselves in the next layer.

Now the input to this next layer, is actually going to be 3d array/kernel that is trainable.
So instead of the filters being trainable it's actually going to be this 3d array that is trainable.

I tried using to build a custom_layer in keras to do this, but I am running into this error:

> > TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: (None, 20, 20, 6, 10). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Here is my attempt:

```
#build my custom layer
from keras.layers import  Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D,Input, Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer
import numpy as np

class MyLayer(Layer):


    def __init__(self,output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.height = output_dim[0] #height
        self.width = output_dim[1] # width
        self.filter = output_dim[2] #filter
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def build(self, input_shape): # input_shape[2] = channels
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
        shape=(input_shape[0],self.height,self.width, input_shape[2],self.filter),
        initializer='uniform',
        trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, inputs):

        outputs = K.conv2d(
                self.kernel, # array to be convolved upon
                inputs, # inputs (feature maps) will be kernel
                strides= 1,
                padding= "same",
                data_format= "channels_last",
                dilation_rate= 1)
        return outputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0],self.output_dim)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    rand_array = np.random.rand(10,10,3)
    model_input = Input(shape = (10,10,3))

    x = Conv2D (kernel_size = (5,5), filters = 10,padding = "valid", activation='relu')(model_input)
    x =MyLayer(output_dim =(20,20,10))(x)
    model = Model(inputs = model_input, outputs = x)
    #x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    print(model.summary())
```

Comment: The first index represents `batch_size`.  Can you advance index by `1` in your `__init__` function and check again?

Comment: @mlRocks  Hi! Thanks for the comment. What part in the `__init__ `function? The output dimensions? If so I advance it `compute_output_shape`